# retrieve the data from Json object

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-ajax

I am learning json now.

```
$.ajax({  
        async: true,  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "get.....values.asp",  
        data: "vendorId="+vendor,  
        success: function(json){    
            alert( "Data retrieved: " + json );   
        }  
    });
```

I am using this ajax call to get the data as json and data is coming as fallowing:

```
{"rows": [  
         {"cell":[  
                  104,100,140,"2.99",0.1,1,14,123.55  
                 ]   
          }   
]}
```

How can i retrieve the data from this json object?
can any one give Idea?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.parseJSON(json)` will do the work.

Comment: Yes Luopan, I got it I have changed the json object as falloing: **var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
alert( obj.rows[0].cell[0] );** my problem solved Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
json.rows[0].cell[0]
```

...etc.?

I also notice you haven't specific the datatype when calling your $.ajax function, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
async: true,
type: "POST",
url: "get.....values.asp",
data: "vendorId="+vendor,
dataType: 'json',
success: mySuccessHandler
});
```

Comment: I tried that way, but failed in fire bug i got the fallowing error json.rows is undefined

Comment: Even when specifying the json data type?

Comment: Yes tomtroughton, I tried now by mentioning like **datatype: "json"** still same error I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it through a for loop in the callback function and assign variables to the bits of information you want to use.